# Passing $_POST values with cURL

Tags: php, post, curl

How do you pass `$_POST` values to a page using `cURL`?

Answer (score 173, accepted):

Should work fine.

```
$data = array('name' => 'Ross', 'php_master' => true);

// You can POST a file by prefixing with an @ (for <input type="file"> fields)
$data['file'] = '@/home/user/world.jpg';

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle)
```

We have two options here, `CURLOPT_POST` which turns HTTP POST on, and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` which contains an array of our post data to submit. This can be used to submit data to `POST` `<form>`s.

---

It is important to note that `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);` takes the $data in two formats, and that this determines how the post data will be encoded.

1. `$data` as an `array()`: The data will be sent as `multipart/form-data` which is not always accepted by the server.

   ```
   $data = array('name' => 'Ross', 'php_master' => true);
   curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
   ```
2. `$data` as url encoded string: The data will be sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is the default encoding for submitted html form data.

   ```
   $data = array('name' => 'Ross', 'php_master' => true);
   curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
   ```

I hope this will help others save their time.

See:

- [`curl_init`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php)
- [`curl_setopt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

Answer (score 31):

[Ross has the right idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395/passing-post-values-with-curl#28411) for POSTing the usual parameter/value format to a url.

I recently ran into a situation where I needed to POST some XML as Content-Type "text/xml" without any parameter pairs so here's how you do that:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><stuff><child>foo</child><child>bar</child></stuff>';
$httpRequest = curl_init();

curl_setopt($httpRequest, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($httpRequest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:  text/xml"));
curl_setopt($httpRequest, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($httpRequest, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);

curl_setopt($httpRequest, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($httpRequest, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

$returnHeader = curl_exec($httpRequest);
curl_close($httpRequest);
```

In my case, I needed to parse some values out of the HTTP response header so you may not necessarily need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` or `CURLOPT_HEADER`.

Comment: This is not what the poster is asking, but it just happens to be exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad someone else found it helpful.

Comment: your 
"curl_setopt($httpRequest, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:  text/xml"));" solved something that took me couple of hours already! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Hi Mark, if you have time, could you please help me out?.. Please. [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854526/post-data-with-file-get-content)

Comment: Spent ours trying to figure out why my xml data was not accepted when sent as urlencoded. The Content-Type and no urlencode saved me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple PHP example of using cURL:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();                    // Initiate cURL
    $url = "http://www.somesite.com/curl_example.php"; // Where you want to post data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  // Tell cURL you want to post something
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=value1&var2=value2&var_n=value_n"); // Define what you want to post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return the output in string format
    $output = curl_exec ($ch); // Execute
    
    curl_close ($ch); // Close cURL handle
    
    var_dump($output); // Show output
?>
```

Instead of using `curl_setopt` you can use `curl_setopt_array`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php

Comment: Thank you!! - Your code `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "var1=value1&var2=value2&var_n=value_n"); // Define what you want to post` provided me with what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$query_string = "";

if ($_POST) {
    $kv = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $kv[] = stripslashes($key) . "=" . stripslashes($value);
    }
    $query_string = join("&", $kv);
}

if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
}

$url = 'https://www.abcd.com/servlet/';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($kv));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$url='Your url'; // Specify your url
$data= array('parameterkey1'=>value,'parameterkey2'=>value); // Add parameters in key value
$ch = curl_init(); // Initialize cURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer? A few lines of code do not an answer make.

Comment: 1) Specify your url    2) Create array of parameters  3) Initialize curl 4) set Required options of curl  5) Execute Curl  6) Close Curl

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    function executeCurl($arrOptions) {

        $mixCH = curl_init();

        foreach ($arrOptions as $strCurlOpt => $mixCurlOptValue) {
            curl_setopt($mixCH, $strCurlOpt, $mixCurlOptValue);
        }

        $mixResponse = curl_exec($mixCH);
        curl_close($mixCH);
        return $mixResponse;
    }

    // If any HTTP authentication is needed.
    $username = 'http-auth-username';
    $password = 'http-auth-password';

    $requestType = 'POST'; // This can be PUT or POST

    // This is a sample array. You can use $arrPostData = $_POST
    $arrPostData = array(
        'key1'  => 'value-1-for-k1y-1',
        'key2'  => 'value-2-for-key-2',
        'key3'  => array(
                'key31'   => 'value-for-key-3-1',
                'key32'   => array(
                    'key321' => 'value-for-key321'
                )
        ),
        'key4'  => array(
            'key'   => 'value'
        )
    );

    // You can set your post data
    $postData = http_build_query($arrPostData); // Raw PHP array

    $postData = json_encode($arrPostData); // Only USE this when request JSON data.

    $mixResponse = executeCurl(array(
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://whatever-your-request-url.com/xyz/yii',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPGET => true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $requestType,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  => $postData,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER  => array(
            "X-HTTP-Method-Override: " . $requestType,
            'Content-Type: application/json', // Only USE this when requesting JSON data
        ),

        // If HTTP authentication is required, use the below lines.
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD  => $username. ':' . $password
    ));

    // $mixResponse contains your server response.
```