# Posting parameters to a url using the POST method without using a form

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I want to post parameters to a URL using the POST method but I cannot use a form. Even if I do use a form, it would have to be auto-posted with out user interaction. Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395/passing-post-values-with-curl

Comment: Is that in any way PHP-related?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use JavaScript and XMLHTTPRequest (AJAX) to perform a POST without using a form. Check [this link](http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php) out. Keep in mind that you will need JavaScript enabled in your browser though.

Comment: This would _not_ work if the URL is on another domain. Right?

Answer (score 27):

Using [jQuery.post](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

```
$.post(
  "http://theurl.com",
  { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" },
  function(data) {
    alert("Response: " + data);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 4):

cURL is an option, using Ajax as well eventhough solving back-end problems with the front-end isn't so neat.

A very useful post about doing it without cURL is this one: http://netevil.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl

The code to do this (untested, unimproved, from the blog post):

```
function do_post_request($url, $data, $optional_headers = null)
{
   $params = array('http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $data
             ));
   if ($optional_headers !== null) {
      $params['http']['header'] = $optional_headers;
   }
   $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
   $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
   if (!$fp) {
      throw new Exception("Problem with $url, $php_errormsg");
   }
   $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
   if ($response === false) {
      throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
   }
   return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How to do it without using cURL with straight-up PHP: http://netevil.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl

Answer (score -1):

it can be done with CURL or AJAX. The response is equally cryptic as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to link to something, rather than do it from code you can redirect your request through: http://getaspost.appspot.com/