# Getting values of a variable from one page to the another

Tags: php

I have a page [page A] that sends variable values to another page[page B]. Currently, I have been using the `$_GET` method to get the values from [page A] on [page B]. This is how the url in [page A] looks like

`$id=2;
 <a href="pageB.php?id=$id">Goto Page B</a>`

and on [Page B]

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
echo $id;
```

In this way I perfectly receive the value of the id from [page A] on [page B].

My questions is, would be possible to receive the value of the id from [page A] onto [page B] without adding `?id=$id` to the url in [page A] ?

Please if yes, how can I do this. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to use [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp), plenty of [tutorials](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) online. Or [cookies](http://www.php.net//manual/en/features.cookies.php). Sessions would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [**$_SESSION**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) variable, which will be available on every page once activated:

Page A:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = 2;
?>
```

Page B:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
        echo $_SESSION['id']; // 2
?>
```

Comment: Just an advice: Try to check if var really exists `isset($_SESSION['id'])` because user may block cookies or delete them before going to Page B.

Comment: Aryt thanks..I was making a research and i found this answer,i want to know if sessions are preferred to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/1244331/2595059.

Comment: @George I would certainly prefer sessions over that answer. Seems unnecessarily complex for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

you want to use sessions here:

```
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['id']= $id;
```

$id can of course be any value.

Comment: The question asks what to use *instead of get variables*