# fopen not working : why is $_POST empty?

Tags: php, post

I have two files active.php and passive.php.
  I want active.php to post data without user interaction to passive.php, as explained
[here](http://wezfurlong.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl/).
  If my code worked, in the end the $_POST array should contain 'Name'=>'John Doe' instead
of being empty as my navigator informs me. What did I do wrong ?

I am fully aware that there are solutions using either Javascript (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244308/posting-parameters-to-a-url-using-the-post-method-without-using-a-form) ) or cURL (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395/passing-post-values-with-curl) ), but this question  is specifically about the PHP-only method, so please do not
post any comment or answer involving Javascript or cURL.

Contents of passive.php :

```
<?php
     var_dump($_POST);
  ?>
```

Contents of active.php :

```
  <?php

   $post_data=array('Name'=>'John Doe');
   $url='http://localhost:8888/passive.php';
   $params = array('http' => array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => $post_data
             ));
   $ctx = stream_context_create($params);
   $fp = @fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);
   $response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
   fclose($fp);
   var_dump($response);

?>
```

Comment: Might want to try adding a Header to your stream context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the PHP manual page itself [found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) the top rated comment explains how to perform a POST operation using stream. As mentioned in the comment above, you're just missing a header

```
$post_data=array('Name'=>'John Doe');
$url='http://localhost:8888/passive.php';

$params = array(
  'http' => array
  (
      'method' => 'POST',
      'header'=>"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      'content' => $post_data
  )
);

$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$fp = fopen($url, 'rb', false, $ctx);

$response = stream_get_contents($fp);
```

Comment: Your solution is incomplete (and does not work on my computer), but on the page you link to I found another tip : replace $post_data with http_build_query($post_data). Combining this with the header works on my computer. Thanks for your indirect help

Comment: @WarrenBeadus - Glad it's sorted and could be of some help :)