# How to CURL to access this website that requires a login?

Tags: curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to cUrl with my premium account on Drupalize.me following [this other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399087/curl-to-access-a-page-that-requires-a-login-from-a-different-page), but all I get back is the logout webpage source.

```
curl --user user:pass --cookie-jar somefile https://drupalize.me/user/login
curl --cookie somefile http://drupalize.me/videos/testing-resources-curl
```

I'll appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Did you read through the entire stackoverflow page you mentioned? it suggests several solutions.

Comment: I did, they gave two solutions, but none of them seems to login on the site, it still returns the non logged page.

Comment: Did you try the one with the cookies?

Comment: both, that one won't even generate the cookies file