# How to login into Graphene Django app using curl?

Tags: django, curl, authentication, graphql

I downloaded django app which has regular django api. App is really big and I decided to implement django graphene module and to make more flexible api.
I have a graphene view which allow sending requests and receiving responses. My problem is that I want to add authentication on graphene view, so every user needs to provide token or username and password to be able to fetch the records.

I found some solution here:
[Adding LoginRequiredMixin in new view](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/master/docs/authorization.rst#adding-login-required)

My problem is I can't login into django app using curl to execute some grapql query.

What I tried so far:

```
curl -u admin:password123 -X GET http://localhost:8003/graphql?query=query%7B%20types%20%7B%20edges%20%7B%20node%20%7B%20name%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D
```

using jwt_auth

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwiZW1haWwiOiIiLCJleHAiOjE0OTg3NDA4OTR9.FvofAxyhvjTGNZBUUSRF1kmXfgTNja6U52NynLhBGeo" http://localhost:8003/graphql?query=query%7B%20types%20%7B%20edges%20%7B%20node%20%7B%20name%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%20%7
```

default app way to login on existing api to my graphene view

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token 2867936fff9d738ee5fc8a807c86a96e59ab648d" http://localhost:8003/graphql?query=query%7B%20types%20%7B%20edges%20%7B%20node%20%7B%20name%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D%20%7D
```

Comment: The way you're trying to login works for Basic HTTP Auth. Django uses cookies, so it won't work this way. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399087/curl-to-access-a-page-that-requires-a-login-from-a-different-page

Answer (score 0):

You can use [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) as an alternative to curl to send graphql queries to your api. It is easy to setup the headers and authenticate.

[django-graphql-auth](https://github.com/PedroBern/django-graphql-auth) have a demo video with insomnia, showing how to register and authenticate an user with it.