# Curl through the SSO page

Tags: curl, single-sign-on, onelogin

I want to test the SSO authentication with curl command line [I'm using OneLogin as an IDP],
But i don't know how to run a curl request to pass through the authentication page

> curl -L -c cookie.txt -d "LoginName=mylogin" -d "password=mypassword"
>   https://example.com curl -b cookie.txt https://example.com

In this example the https://example.com is the link of the page secured with OneLogin IDP

for the second request, i received the page:

```
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="linkttoIDP">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

do you have any idea to pass through the sso with command line ??

Thank you in advance

Comment: I found this answer from another thread very helpful!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42028789/3452486