# How to download from a website that requires logging in username/password, using a batch file?

Tags: file, batch-file, download, web, microsoft-edge

I saw questions of this for other types of files but not batch. I don't know much about code, but I have an idea.

Open up the link in Microsoft Edge (because it's already logged into the website), and download it from there. I don't know how to make the batch file to OPEN and DOWNLOAD using Microsoft Edge though. Is this possible?

To open, I think it's this:

```
start microsoft-edge:http://www.cnn.com
```

How do I download it after opening Edge?

Comment: Batch files cannot interact with Graphical User Interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly batch file, but using tools that are already part of Windows, you can [fetch web content with Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/344927/powershell-equivalent-of-curl), which according to the article, can simulate the Unix `curl` command.

Another way, if you absolutely insist on using batch, is to [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710748/run-curl-commands-from-windows-console) the `curl` command and then use the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399087/curl-to-access-a-page-that-requires-a-login-from-a-different-page#12399176) to help you get further, using cookies to keep track of the login between multiple invocations of curl.

Basic usage is easy, but maybe you need a [curl tutorial](http://www.yilmazhuseyin.com/blog/dev/curl-tutorial-examples-usage/) to help you do this.

There is another tool called `wget` that has similar functionality and may be a better or easier method for you. Mileage may vary.

Comment: Ordinarily, "use this tool" answers would be frowned upon, but this is really the only way to do it.

Comment: Fair. And I've since learned that Powershell has the curl-like `Invoke-WebRequest` function which is supposedly aliased as curl and wget. So I've updated my answer to match.