# Scraping method for a webpage

Tags: python, node.js, web-scraping, scrape

I have tried everything! From curl to Phantomjs, cheerio. I am trying to scrape an [Easports](http://www.easports.com/dynasty/schedule) URL but every time I try, the login form stops me...

Is there any way of scraping this page?

Also, if there isn't, is there an API for the data I want to scrape?

Comment: this is possibly helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399087/curl-to-access-a-page-that-requires-a-login-from-a-different-page

Comment: Obviously if there is the data you want to scrape requires authentication, you have to figure out how the auth mechanism works and follow that procedure before you scrape. Also you have to tell us what you want to scrape, maybe it is available via rss or api.

Comment: There is no api for ncaa football 14 data, so I'm trying scraping

Comment: @alexshchep I've tried it, no result