# Access Denied when accessing site using curl

Tags: curl, access-denied

```sh
curl "https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=BANKNIFTY"
```

I am trying this code in my terminal but an "Access Denied" error pops up every time I run it:

[image: My command output]

Comment: I'm can not see how this has anything to do with Python

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69030138/error-in-open-connectioncon-rb-http-error-401

Answer (score 2):

that website runs on a user-agent whitelist, and curl is not on their whitelist. seems the easiest way to get around it is to fake the user-agent, an example of a whitelisted user-agent is `Chrome/79`,

```
 curl --user-agent 'Chrome/79' 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-derivative?symbol=BANKNIFTY'
```

protip: that website loads much faster if you add the argument `--compressed` - it gzips really well, here it goes from 
~1400 milliseconds response time to ~600 milliseconds response time (on a shitty 4G connection from Tjøme, Norway :P )

Comment: This is working perfectly, now can I use this in my python code .

Answer (score -1):

That script i think uses variables from that spesific website so therefore variables is undefined when you run it in you terminal, try to run it in the web console instead.

Comment: See if maybe one of these will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102985/how-to-debug-curl-access-denied ,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399087/curl-to-access-a-page-that-requires-a-login-from-a-different-page/12399176

Comment: it has nothing to do with variables. it just runs on a User-Agent whitelist, and curl is not on their whitelist. check my answer below~