# Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 401

Tags: r, http-error, jsonlite, fromjson

I am trying to extract option table for security **IOC** from the website https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain

The JSON link containing the data is
https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=IOC

When i try to import data into R, i get an error,

```
library(jsonlite)
dat=fromJSON("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=IOC")
Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 401.
```

But surprisingly when I open webiste https://www.nseindia.com/option-chain in Chrome/Firefox and select the **IOC** stock and then use the `fromJSON` it works.

Why such behavior? and
How can I get the data without opening web browser?

Comment: The behavior you see is most likely an attempt to stop scraping. Looking at their [robots.txt](https://www.nseindia.com/robots.txt) you can also see, that they don't want people to scrape anything in the "/api/" path. They do have a CSV download option, maybe that works for your purposes?

Comment: Thanks, sure the CSV files works but can get it through `rvest` or `httr`?

Comment: The download link for the CSV is "protected" by Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to check your "user-agent" value and block requests from everything that doesn't look like a manually controlled browser. To circumvent this you can change your "user-agent" in a `httr::GET()` request.

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)
httr::GET("https://httpbin.org/user-agent",
          config = add_headers("user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0"))
raw <-
  GET(
    "https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-equities?symbol=IOC",
    config = add_headers("user-agent" = "Mozilla/5.0")
  ) |>
  read_html()

raw |>
  html_nodes("p") |>
  html_text() |>
  jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

Comment: `read_html` is not working for this link. There is no output.