# Wget to download data from a javascript authenticated webpage

Tags: wget

i am trying to download data from a webpage that uses post method and uses javascript to pass the username/password to function called login.do

is there a way to connect and download the data of the webpage.

please let me know if you need any more information about the situation.

i tried using wget --save-cookies cookies.txt http://x.x.x.x:80

but it doesnt go pass the connecting stage.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget), which is similar to yours. Basically, you will probably have to inspect the POST request and make one yourself using wget that contains the necessary login information.