# Using Wget To Connect To Browser

Tags: linux, download, terminal, wget

I want to download all my "liked" images on Tumblr, but I cannot seem to get wget to connect to the page. I really don't even know really where to start. I tried using this code.

```
wget -r -P -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png http://www.tumblr.com/likes
```

But it just downloaded Tumblr in general.. Is there anyway to connect to Tumblr, login, and then navigate wget to my "likes" page?

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1432161/1454048). Basically, you need to create a login session, and *then* `wget` whatever you need to from that authenticated session.

Comment: @admdrew could you explain what a couple of these commands do and how they work? 

`wget --save-cookies cookies.txt`
`--post-data 'user=foo&password=bar'`
`http://server.com/auth.php`
`wget --load-cookies cookies.txt`
`-p http://server.com/interesting/article.php`

And how do I find the authentication PHP page?

Comment: Well, you're going to need to figure out some of that stuff yourself, but just as is shown in the code on that answer I linked you to, the first `wget` sends the `POST` variables `user` and `password` to the server, using `cookies.txt` for a session cookie, and the second `wget` accesses another page on that server using the session cookie that was just created. The "authentication PHP page" you're looking for is any page that Tumblr allows a login at (ie, `http://www.tumblr.com`). You'll need to view page source to find out what the correct `POST` variables are, however.

Comment: The only problem with the technic @admdrew is that Tumblr uses a JS login.