# how to make a script or batch file to download a ppsx from sharepoint?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, wget

I'm using wget to download a ppsx file from SharePoint but I keep getting a '403 forbidden' error can someone help me on how to fix the error? or if someone can guide me on how to create a batch file to download a file from SharePoint that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

I have used wget (link) and I keep getting a 403 error or only a small 190kb of the file is downloaded.

Comment: Can you add more information what you are trying to do? do you try to schedule a task that does it regularly? should this file be public or do you need an authenticated session? Do you know that you might connect to SharePoint like you do with a file share? that will fit your needs better. Another alternative would be to use the built-in synchronization possibilities. Both ways are well described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-a-network-drive-to-a-sharepoint-library-751148de-f579-42f9-bc8c-fcd80ccf0f53

Answer (score 0):

> keep getting a 403 error

[403](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) is **Forbidden**, you are informed you are not allowed to download this file.

> only a small 190kb of the file is downloaded.

Try to open it using text editor. I guess it contain above information, but maybe also information what you should do in order to get access.

> using wget to download a ppsx file from SharePoint

Then answers in [Download file/folder from sharepoint using Curl/Wget automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924014/download-file-folder-from-sharepoint-using-curl-wget-automatically) might be useful for you