# Wget to access university pdf

Tags: linux, cookies, wget

I am trying to use wget to download a pdf from my university website
the url looks something like this : 
https://online.myuni.ac.uk/webapps/blackboard/execute/content/file?cmd=view&content_id=_xxxxxxx_1&course_id=_xxxxx_1

I have tried using wget with both cookies and also with --user=xxx --password=xxx
However what it downloads is a html page showing me a log-in screen saying I have insufficient permission.
I cannot get this to work, and I am not sure how to proceed. I am very inexperienced with linux and programming in general any help is appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget

Comment: I have looked there, I did the same method of exporting cookies from a browser, and I have tried the log in options too. I want to use wget in this particular instance and I am not interested in using curl.

Comment: You'll need to adjust the login field names to those in your login form. The way explained there really is *the* way to do it using wget.

Comment: try to use url in double quotes wget "https://online.myuni.ac.uk/webapps/blackboard/execute/content/file?cmd=view&content_id=_xxxxxxx_1&course_id=_xxxxx_1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working by exporting cookies from a browser, but the key was to include the "keep-session-cookies" parameter.