# How can I get around a TYPO3 login mask with wget?

Tags: typo3, wget

I've tried fetching sites from a TYPO3 page using wget following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1432161/4252230).

But it did not work, since I do not see a target for the login form.

It calls `TYPO3FrontendLoginFormRsaEncryption.submitForm()` as `onsubmit`.

I can't show you the website, but I figure this should be common with TYPO3 pages.

Is there a way to get behind the login form?

Comment: You have to find out, what the javascript finally posts to the backend and simulate that. Please be aware, that WGET does not have a javascript interpreter, so you will have to do the server requests manually.

Comment: Do you need to fetch them periodically or just one time?

Comment: One time would be enough, @JozefSpisiak

Answer (score 2):

For one time access just login from the computer and then use the cookie you get from the same computer / IP address in the script. You can get them with browser developer tools. Depending on the security settings, you might need to send also the same user agent header as browser you used to login, which you can check with developer tools as well.

Comment: Sounds amazingly simple and straight forward. Will try.