# How to get past the login page with Headless Chrome and output many DOMs?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I'm trying to accomplish two things with the new Headless Chrome:

1) import my existing Chrome cookies into Headless. Either using a similar technique to [wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget)'s "--save-cookies cookies.txt" or through some other means.

2) when I output the dom (using --dump-dom), I'd like the output not to overwrite the existing output file. I've been struggling with this for a while, and hoping someone can point me in the right direction!