# Download a file from remote server that requires authentication using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, sh, wget

I want to download a file from the Jenkins server that requires authentication(username and password) using Dockerfile

below provided is the first two lines of my Dockerfile

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcompat
```

and then I have

```
ENV REPO_USERNAME=test
ENV REPO_PASSWORD=testPassword
```

the eclipse-temurin:17-alpine contains wget, so I assume I do not need to install it additionally
, so I imagine the solution will look like

`RUN wget --user="$REPO_USERNAME" --password="$REPO_PASSWORD" -O reqLoader-linux http://10.80․10․2/tools/puppeteer-v13/reqLoader-linux`

but when running the Dockerfile I am getting this error message

```
#14 [10/14] RUN wget --user="test" --password="testPassword" -O reqLoader-linux http://10.80.10.2/tools/puppeteer-v13/reqLoader-linux
#14 0.272 wget: unrecognized option: password=testPassword
#14 0.275 BusyBox v1.36.1 (2023-07-27 17:12:24 UTC) multi-call binary.
#14 0.275
#14 0.275 Usage: wget [-cqS] [--spider] [-O FILE] [-o LOGFILE] [--header STR]
#14 0.275       [--post-data STR | --post-file FILE] [-Y on/off]
#14 0.275       [-P DIR] [-U AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...
#14 0.275
#14 0.275 Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP
#14 0.275
#14 0.275       --spider        Only check URL existence: $? is 0 if exists
#14 0.275       --header STR    Add STR (of form 'header: value') to headers
#14 0.275       --post-data STR Send STR using POST method
#14 0.275       --post-file FILE        Send FILE using POST method
#14 0.275       -c              Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
#14 0.275       -q              Quiet
#14 0.275       -P DIR          Save to DIR (default .)
#14 0.275       -S              Show server response
#14 0.275       -T SEC          Network read timeout is SEC seconds
#14 0.275       -O FILE         Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
#14 0.275       -o LOGFILE      Log messages to FILE
#14 0.275       -U STR          Use STR for User-Agent header
#14 0.275       -Y on/off       Use proxy
#14 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c wget --user=\"$REPO_USERNAME\" --password=\"$REPO_PASSWORD\" -O reqLoader-linux http://10.80․10․2/tools/puppeteer-v13/reqLoader-linux" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
------
 > [10/14] RUN wget --user="test" --password="testPassword" -O reqLoader-linux http://10.80․10․2/tools/puppeteer-v13/reqLoader-linux:
0.275   --post-file FILE        Send FILE using POST method
0.275   -c              Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
0.275   -q              Quiet
0.275   -P DIR          Save to DIR (default .)
0.275   -S              Show server response
0.275   -T SEC          Network read timeout is SEC seconds
0.275   -O FILE         Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
0.275   -o LOGFILE      Log messages to FILE
0.275   -U STR          Use STR for User-Agent header
0.275   -Y on/off       Use proxy
------
Dockerfile:18
--------------------
  16 |
  17 |     # Download reqLoader-linux and move it to the puppeteer directory
  18 | >>> RUN wget --user="$REPO_USERNAME" --password="$REPO_PASSWORD" -O reqLoader-linux http://10.80․10․2/tools/puppeteer-v13/reqLoader-linux
```

I see that the problem comes from providing the username and password in the command because there is no that kind of parameter

Detail - I am running Dockerfile using .sh file in git bash(windows 11)

Any other suggestion on how to download files using Dockerfile from remote server that requires authentication is very much appreciated

The purpose of this is to have those files in the image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get past the login page with Wget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324421/how-to-get-past-the-login-page-with-wget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are using wget, but Alpine Linux doesn’t support “—user” and “—password” directly.
So try using curl, which would look like this:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl

ENV REPO_USERNAME=test
ENV REPO_PASSWORD=testPassword

RUN curl --user "$REPO_USERNAME:$REPO_PASSWORD" -o reqLoader-linux http://10.80.10.2/tools/puppeteer-v13/reqLoader-linux
```