# Giving input to a Java program from PHP while Java program is running

Tags: java, php

I am getting user input from a website, though PHP, the Java program is running on my server, it takes the user input, does some magic and spits back a response in the form of an HTML page.

The problem that I am having is that I only want to start the java program once, because there is some heavy lifting that needs to be done only once. But then I want to keep the Java running and just get it to react to the input from the website.

My method to pass information from PHP is by calling a command prompt command, with the appropriate args. Now obviously I can't use args after the program started.

I need some sort of Buffer or Input Stream, something that will give me pretty much instantaneous response time.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you just add a Tomcat to your setup to run your java app as a servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three alternatives:

1. Using sockets. You can make your java application become some sort of a "server" that receives request and then "respond" to them. The same way your HTTP server works (but of course on a different port).
   This article explains [how to work with java sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html). ([searched for:java socket programming](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=java+socket+programming))
   And this one explains [working with sockets from php](http://www.christophh.net/2012/07/24/php-socket-programming/) ([searched for:php socket programming](https://www.google.com.eg/search?q=php+socket+programming))
2. Making your java application single-instance [check this](http://www.rbgrn.net/content/43-java-single-application-instance) to save start-up time, but this way you will have to write response in files or something.
3. Put your java code in a servlet, run it inside a web container, and redirect the requests from your php page to the servlet. [refer to ths question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923220/how-to-redirect-to-another-jsp-page-in-php)

Comment: I would suggest answer 3.

Comment: ended up going with a socket, works like a charm for what I need, thank you