# POSTing php variable

Tags: php, variables, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing $_POST values with cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395/passing-post-values-with-curl)

I have a php variable `$abc` (text type). And I want to POST this data to `http://www.example.com/xyz.php` How can I do this? I cant use GET.

Comment: Use cURL.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395/passing-post-values-with-curl

Answer (score 2):

You could use [cURL extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/xyz.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$post = array(
    'key' => 'value'
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_exec($curl);
```