# How do you add a post action in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, action

I'm using a captch system I found on line to protect my form. I have used it several times in the past but have always used the `mailto` function, this time I need to use an action url and do not know the syntax

Here is the captcha script

```
<?php 
session_start();

if( isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if( $_SESSION['security_code'] == $_POST['security_code'] && !empty($_SESSION['security_code'] ) ) {
        // Insert you code for processing the form here, e.g emailing the submission, entering it into a database. 
        action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST"
        echo 'Thank you. Your info has been submitted.';
        unset($_SESSION['security_code']);
   } else {
        // Insert your code for showing an error message here
        echo 'Sorry, you have provided an invalid security code';
   }
} else {
?>
```

it needs to submit to

```
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="oid" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
```

this is for submission to my salesforce.

Comment: I suggest posting your form directly to the "salesforce" page and processing the data there. Failing that, you may need to use AJAX to re-post the data to the "salesforce" page after processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use SalesForce API instead direct POST.
Here you can see their documentation:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm

You should use SOAP client to do requests to SalesForce, but they have build API you can use, so use it. It is easyer way.

Comment: the form I am using is from slaes force web to lead generatin wizard, I then added the captcha part to it, sales force suggest using the post method that is why I trying to get this to work. It wors with out the capthca so I simply want ot add on...

Comment: hm. I don't think you can directly send form data to SalesForce. But if you do you should use curl

Answer (score 0):

You may use curl, fsockopen or file_get_contents to make a post request within PHP.
cURL is recommended. There are lots of examples around:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28411/286619

Don't forget to enable the curl extension...