# PHP send data with POST in a redirect

Tags: php, forms, post, curl

I should send data without a form from a page to another! How? I know that curl "asks" data, but I have not to ask them, I have to send!
With poor words, I uses a validator to check data for sign up. If something is not valid, it has to send data back with an error message! How I could send back without encoding them in URL?
Thanks before!

Comment: All web communication has two parts,  a request and a response.  If you are receiving/handling a request, you simply output the answer as the response.

Comment: You may use session or query string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395/passing-post-values-with-curl ?

Comment: I have the old manner I used: Setting Session. But I would use $_POST. I have not some code to show, cause I have not idea what to do and I haven't found anything. I have not a request. I have to send a message to another page. I would like to do with POST!

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do it.
you can use session. so you can save the data in an array
and save the array in session
and after you redirect the user to the form with error
you have to check if the array is set so you can print errors and data you want
then unset the variable you used in session.

Comment: Something that doesn't include $_SESSION? Nothing with $_POST?

Comment: <?php
$url = 'http://server.com/path';
$data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');
 
// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
  'http' => array(
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'content' => http_build_query($data),
  ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
 
var_dump($result);