# Convert cURL to be used in php function

Tags: php, curl, box-api, box

Currently im working on [box](https://docs.box.com/reference#upload-a-file) platform, and trying to upload a file to the box server. Box uses cURL to upload files, and i'm trying to send cURl requests from php. So far i've converted most of the cURL commads to php jargon, but i could't figure out how to pass in the attributes(name, path, containing folder) of the file to be uploaded.

here is the cURL

```
curl https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content -H "Authorization: Bearer APP_USER_TOKEN" -X POST -F attributes='{"name":"Jon_Snow.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"0"}}' -F file=@Jon_Snow.jpeg
```

and here is the php version for the incomplete cURL command.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://upload.box.com/api/2.0/files/content");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".json_decode($accessToken, true )['access_token'];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

How do i do the last part of the cURL command which is

```
-F attributes='{"name":"Jon_Snow.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"0"}}' -F file=@Jon_Snow.jpeg
```

Edit: the suggestion of 'possible duplicate' is not accurate, i am asking of a way to add attributes to the uploaded files in the form `-F attributes='{"name":"Jon_Snow.jpeg", "parent":{"id":"0"}}'` i dont see how the suggested answer is relevant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing $\_POST values with cURL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28395/passing-post-values-with-curl)

Comment: this is not just uploading file using cURL, please notice the attribute section of the command its a nested attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, i needed to `json_encode` the attributes array and then use `new \CURLFile()` function to create a file handle, it did NOT work with `realpath()`

```
$attributes = array('name'=>$fileName,'parent'=>array('id'=>$folderId));
$file = new \CURLFile($filePath);
$fields = array('attributes' => json_encode($attributes), 'file' => $file);
$headers = array("Authorization: Bearer ".$accessToken);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uploadUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this: [art about sending files via post and curlib](https://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/)

-F option means you're sending a post Field with name and content. Content in this case is from File becasue you're using @ prefix

Comment: Please add relevant parts of the link to provide users with assistance in case the link goes dead.

Comment: did you check when the post was made, the functions work with php 5.5+ i'm using php 5.6