# PHP: how to convert shell_exec( cURL ) into Guzzle format?

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, shell-exec

The below cURL works while running shell exec but how do I format this in Guzzle?

```
shell_exec('curl https://*********************** -H "Authorization: *********************** -X POST -F attributes=\'{"name":"testFile.txt", "parent":{"id":"***********"}}\' -F file=@path/To/File.txt');
```

I want to convert the shell_exec into Guzzle format like the code below but it produces this error:

> Client error: `POST https://***********************`
>   resulted in a `405 Method Not Allowed

```
$response = $client->request('POST', 'https://***********************', [
    'debug' => true,
    'headers' => $headers,
    'form_params' => [
        'attributes' => [
            'name' => 'testFile.txt',
            'parent' => [
                'id' => '***********',
             ]
        ],
     'file' => '@path/To/File.txt',
    ]
]);
```

Any idea what I need to change?

Comment: `Error 405` has nothing to do with your code .. It's that the **remote** server isn't allowing the protocol you're trying to perform.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zak already said, `405` is the server's response, it's has nothing to do with your code. You should get the same response with cURL.

BTW, to send files you need [`multipart`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#multipart), not `form_params`. And Guzzle doesn't support `@...` notation as command-line cURL does. So see the docs, there is an example.

Comment: Thank you for your responses! I found my solution by converting it to a PHP function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41179847/convert-curl-to-be-used-in-php-function