# How to execute this curl command in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

Executing this curl command from terminal is working and i am getting back my results.

```
curl -F "file=@/var/www/html/uploads/fb5bc34e1f0f03c759e92010f6a1a302_modified.csv" http://10.0.0.106:8089/uploadAndMatch/ -o ~/out.txt
```

But when trying it from PHP with the following code I am getting 400 httpcode:

```
    $request = curl_init('http://10.0.0.106:8089/uploadAndMatch/');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($request,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
    array(
        'file' => '@/var/www/html/uploads/fb5bc34e1f0f03c759e92010f6a1a302_modified.csv'
    ));
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    echo curl_exec($request);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($request, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    echo $httpcode;
    curl_close($request);
```

I also tried to add a header :

```
$header = array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

But it's still the same error! `400 bad request`
Any thoughts?

It wasn't a debugging problem, it's because the [changes](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/curl-file-upload) in php5.5+

Comment: can you compare the actual requests (curl, php+curl) with wireshark? do you have access to the servers code/logs?

Comment: also, maybe your server does not support form-data as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28411/7926064) so maybe try [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Php - Debugging Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl)

Comment: I figured it out, none of the suggested stuff in the comments. I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the curl command from PHP is not reading the file content, but it was reading the path of the file as a post parameter.

```
    $request = curl_init('http://10.0.0.106:8089/uploadAndMatch/');
    // send a file
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    $fileName = explode("/", $file);
    $fileName = end($fileName);
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) { // php 5.5+
      $cFile = curl_file_create($file,'text/csv',$fileName );
    } else { //
      $cFile = '@' . realpath('/var/www/html/uploads/ss.csv');
    }
    $post = array('file'=> $cFile);
    curl_setopt($request,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

and the second problem i solved was that the file in `curl_create_file($fileName)` was sent to the server as a full path and using `curl_file_create($filename, $mimetype = '', $postname = '')` fixed it for me.